# FloatingActionButton is adding extra margin above NestedScrollView in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I'm struggling with strange behaviour of margin with FloatingActionButton in CoordinatorLayout. FAB adds extra margin which disappears after certain actions.

I followed [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/4dfeabfbd083e06d97c7d5ac851a00b8c0ebc792/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml) example to create detail view. I have exactly the xml same structure. The only difference is that I'm using this view for a fragment instead of raw activity.

This occurs most of the times but sometimes it doesn't. Occurs only once for fragment object, once it fixes itself it works well. On my second phone it doesn't occur. After removing FAB it's ok. When I change sth in calendar, it also causes margin to fix itself.

Attaching gif with layout lines enabled so you can see the margins.

[image: margin bug gif]

For reference:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.habitsteacher.android.view.fragment.show.ShowHabitFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="72dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="24dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/intentionText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/icons"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_subhead_material"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.25"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_show_habit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/habit_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="32dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/calendarWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="343dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button_edit_habit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any thought what could be the reason, or how to investigate this deeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't work properly inside a fragment which is added as non-first to the activity. This looks like a bug in SDK but I couldn't locate the root cause precisely.

As it works properly only when the layout is located on the first added fragment to the activity, I moved fragment with this layout to separate activity and is works properly now.

Still, it's avoiding this behaviour not fixing it so any answer is still appreciated.

Comment: Any insight as to the issue? I'm getting the same behavior when I swap add views programmatically to add a crossfade.

Comment: Not really. Applying my workaround for your case would probably be moving these views to separate activities and switch between them. I wish that I knew proper solution for that but I couldn't find anything really, and debugging android layout managers is a tough task.